# 400 Bad Request From React Axios Graphql SageX3

Tags: reactjs, graphql, cors, csrf, sage

I've been stuck for a month now I really need help.
So I've got this react project, I want to get data from this URL: http://{x3server}/xtrem/api (already configured the link in the connected application of sage X3), when I test with postman i get results (with graphql or http post "raw json") I get result with the two methods, So now when I try to execute from React I get 400 bad request, I've checked the headers, the token and the query everything seems to be the same as postman.

Can anyone help me please.

Update: In nodelocal.js (sageX3) i got CSRF security error, knowing that i configured this for CORS already :

```
`security: {
http: {
headers: {
"access-control-allow-origin": "*"
},

        "allow": "POST, GET"
    },
    cors: {
    
        "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With, soapaction, x-requested-with, x-xtrem-endpoint",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
    }

},
`
```